# Spark: count number of specific letter in RDD using aggregate function

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I'm doing a simple assignment in Apache Spark using Python. Let's say I have an RDD:

```
[('python', 1), ('spark', 1), ('context', 1), ('create', 1), ('scala', 1), ('parallel', 1), ('operation', 1), ('apache', 1), ('partition', 1), ('lambda', 1), ('class', 1), ('rdd', 1)]
```

And I want to count the number of occurrences of the letter 's' in the RDD. Using 'map' I would do it like this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('python', 1), ('spark', 1), ('context', 1), ('create', 1), ('scala', 1), ('parallel', 1), ('operation', 1), ('apache', 1), ('partition', 1), ('lambda', 1), ('class', 1), ('rdd', 1)])
rdd.map(lambda x: x[0].count('s')).sum()
```

Now I have to do the same thing but using the 'aggregate' function. But I have no idea how this is done. Any ideas?

Comment: Please acknowledge that according to the [site rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rdd
  .aggregate(0, lambda i, x: i + x[0].count('s'), lambda i, j: i+j)
```

I didn't try that, but it should be simple; the first argument is the zeroValue, or just `0` in our case since the result type is integer. Next is the accumulating function within each partition - in our case count the letter `s` on each row (`x`) and add to the accumulated count (`i`). Last function combines the results from all partitions, again in our case a straightforward sum.

It should be mentioned that PySpark has great documentation on the official Spark website and you could have find the answer there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I specifically have to use RDD's "aggregate" function